# How do I pass a vector and return a vector of strings?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to pass a vector and return a vector of strings in order to solve the anagram exercise on [exercism.io](http://exercism.io).

Here is the test that I'm trying to pass:

```
fn test_no_matches() {
    let inputs = ["hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"];
    let outputs: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    assert_eq!(anagrams_for("diaper", &inputs), outputs);
}
```

and here is what I have written so far:

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, inp: Vec<&'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut out: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    let ref poss = *inp[1];
    out.push(poss);
    out
}
```

But the test fails to compile at `&inputs`, giving me this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:39
  |
4 |     assert_eq!(anagrams_for("diaper", &inputs), outputs);
  |                                       ^^^^^^^
  |                                       |
  |                                       expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found `&[&str; 4]`
  |                                       help: try using a conversion method: `(&inputs).to_vec()`
  |
  = note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<&str>`
          found reference `&[&str; 4]`
```

I've read about references, borrowing, and lifetimes. I can honestly say that I am a bit confused about passing references around. I thought about the return vector as just a `Vec<String>` but I think there was an issue about the input vectors reference to a str that was causing the problems.

If anyone could push me in a better direction that would be appreciated as I don't want to Kirk the test.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4jsvsz/exercismio_rust_problem/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your function signature from

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, inp: Vec<&'a str>) -> Vec<&'a str>
```

to

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, inp: &[&'a str]) -> Vec<&'a str>
```

`&[T]` can accept both `v: Vec<T>` and `v: [T; n]` as arguments by using `&v`.

Comment: That is what it was. I've been reading the docs but couldn't figure out that the signature was &[&'a str] to get at the vector correctly. Thanks I learned something about accessing the ptr. BIG THANKS!!

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:39
  |
4 |     assert_eq!(anagrams_for("diaper", &inputs), outputs);
  |                                       ^^^^^^^
  |                                       |
  |                                       expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found `&[&str; 4]`
  |                                       help: try using a conversion method: `(&inputs).to_vec()`
  |
  = note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<&str>`
          found reference `&[&str; 4]`
```

See how the compiler points to where the error is occurring? The error message states that you should be passing a `Vec<&str>` (a vector of string slices), but instead you are passing a `&[&str; 4]` (a reference to an array of length four containing string slices). These two types are not the same!

To make your code work, you could transform the array into a vector:

```
anagrams_for("diaper", inputs.to_vec());
```

Or you could construct a vector to start with:

```
let inputs = vec!["hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"];
anagrams_for("diaper", inputs);
```

But both of those are silly because you are allocating a vector and never using any of the power that it gives you. Instead, you really just want to accept a slice of string slices:

```
fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, inp: &[&'a str]) -> Vec<&'a str>
```

A reference to an array can be implicitly converted to a slice, as can a reference to a `Vec`, so accepting a slice is often the best choice, when it applies.

Comment: What you did was Kirk the test which I can't do. I put the first part to show how my function is called. I have to conform my public function to match the call in the test.

Comment: @macshaggy maybe my answer is poorly organized, but the last answer (the real one) is only a change to your implementation code, and does not involve any changes to the test.